# bottom sheet not closing on outside click in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material-6, angular-cdk

I am using angular 6 material and I have implemented the bottom sheet in my code. I have use the code given on the material website. I have import all the necessary modules.

Problem: bottom sheet not closing on outside click and also not getting a transparent background.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS0ZR.png)

Comment: Can you show us your code? And if possible, reproduce the error through a stackblitz demo?

Comment: Try this [Material Bottomsheet](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview) or please post some code.

Comment: openBottomSheet(type): void {
    let tabName = { name: type };
    this._bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverview, {
      data: tabName,
      ariaLabel: 'Share on social media',
      closeOnNavigation: true,
      disableClose: false
    });
  }

Comment: and if I try with (https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/examples) this example the also I have the same problem

Comment: i have import all the modules

Answer (score 0):

try removing the disable close, I tested your code in stackbliz and it works, I there any error in the console?

Comment: remove the entire disableClose: false

Comment: like

openBottomSheet(type): void { let tabName = { name: type }; this._bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverview, { data: tabName, ariaLabel: 'Share on social media', closeOnNavigation: true }); }

Comment: <div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop cdk-overlay-dark-backdrop cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div>

when click button and  I inspect bottom sheet HTML I don't find this code in my HTML but it is there in angular website code

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue .
I fixed it by changing the value of `hasBackdrop` to **true** in module.ts
In documentation , it is set to false .
Maybe this will fix it .

Comment: Please provide more description for further detail.